# Derivation of transmon hamiltonian in charge basis

Tags: quantum-information, hamiltonian, superconductivity

In Girvin lectures on superconducting qubits I found this statement

[image]

Is this formula really phenomenological? I didn't find any books with its derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not phenomological, it follows from the rules of quantization. This follows from this form of hamiltonian:
$$ \hat{H} = E_J (1-\mathrm{cos}\: \hat{\phi})) $$
It is the energy stored in Josephson junction. Constant shift of energy can be dropped out and we can theat only cosine function of phase in charge basis. To do so, we employ commutation relationship between charge and phase:
$$ [ \hat{\phi}, \hat{N} ] = i $$
From this you can derive this expession:
$$ [ \hat{\phi}^k, \hat{N} ] = ki\hat{\phi}^{k-1}  $$
which is analogous to coordinate-momentum commutator in usual QM. To proceed then we find $e^{i\hat{\phi}}$ in charge basis:
$$ 
e^{i\hat{\phi}}N = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(i\hat{\phi})^k}{k!}N = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} N \frac{(i\hat{\phi})^k}{k!} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ik(i\hat{\phi})^{k-1}}{k!}N = Ne^{i\hat{\phi}} - e^{i\hat{\phi}} $$
Therefore
$$ e^{i\hat{\phi}} \hat{N} = (\hat{N}-1) e^{i\hat{\phi}} $$
And finally
$$ e^{i\hat{\phi}} = |N\rangle \langle N-1|$$
This immediately leads to the expression for cosine function in charge basis and then to the formula from book.