# Link between the charge and the phase in a superconducting circuit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, superconductivity

I have a question related to superconducting quantum circuits. Especially regarding the derivation of the transformation of $\cos(\phi)$ in the charge basis.

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713072/), a user states that assuming a large number of Cooper pairs, one gets $e^{i\hat{\phi}} \hat{N} = (\hat{N}-1) e^{i\hat{\phi}}$. That I totally understand and have managed to derive.

However, I can not find the way to go to the last equation: $e^{i\hat{\phi}} = |N\rangle \langle N-1|$.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bracket your relation:
$$
\langle N=M|e^{i\phi}N|N=M’\rangle =\langle N=M|(N-1)e^{i\phi}|N=M’\rangle \\
M’\langle N=M|e^{i\phi}|N=M’\rangle =(M-1)\langle N=M|e^{i\phi}|N=M’\rangle \\
\langle N=M|e^{i\phi}|N=M’\rangle\propto \delta_{M-1,M’}
$$
so:
$$
e^{i\phi} =\sum u_N |N+1\rangle\langle N|
$$
by unitarity and if the eigenbasis is normalized $|u_N|=1$.

Without additional assumptions on the eigenbasis, you cannot go further. Indeed, you can multiply your basis vectors by arbitrary phases giving you any values for $u_N$. Actually, you typically construct the eigenbasis by induction using:
$$
e^{i\phi}|N\rangle=|N+1\rangle
$$
so that the formula is true by definition. The definition by induction will be a valid eigenbasis from your first formula.

Mathematically, it is the same (up to a sign) as position-momentum:
$$
[x,p]=-i
$$
In this case, $e^{ip}$ is a translation in position. To make the analogy more accurate, it’s best to think of $x$ to be periodic so that $p$ is discrete (particle in periodic box) or $p$ periodic and $x$ discrete (particle on lattice).

Hope this helps.